# Next.js 13.4.13 (app router) data revalidation randomly no longer working

Tags: next.js, sanity

I know it's not helpful, but I have no idea why or what has changed to stop my revalidation. I have a sanity.io + next.js project where I am using GROQ to call and fetch new data, which has been working fine for months, but today, it is no longer revalidating and I don't know why.

I have a page that looks something like:

```
export default async function Page({params}) {
    const { globalData, page } = await fetchContent(GET_PAGE_BY_SLUG, { slug: params.slug })

    if (!tool) {
      notFound()
    }

    const {
        images,
        title,
        body,
        related,
        relatedByCategory
    } = page || {}

    return (
      -- template --
    )
}
```

The `fetchContent` function that is handling the data fetching looks like:

```
import client from '@/utils/sanity/client'

const clientFetch = client.fetch.bind(client)

export default async function fetchContent(query, options) {
    const res = await clientFetch(
        query,
        {
            ...options,
            next: { revalidate: 60 }
        }
    )
    return res
}
```

Comment: It's never worked for my team and there are a ton of issues around it posted in their issue tracker. Here is one of the latest: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/49417

Comment: Yeah, but it's Next. Surely it does work. I'm a front-of-frontend developer so this kinda thing is a bit newer to me, but this is insane that I can't fetch new data so easily.

Comment: But also, where does this leave Next.js? If revalidation is inconsistent and buggy, should I be considering moving to another framework, because this is shocking how bad this is.

Comment: The app dir in Next feels alpha/beta with over 2.1k (not all app dir) unresolved GitHub issues. On the other hand, the pages dir is reliable and I've used it for years. If you're new, I'd recommend checking out the pages dir and migrating after the app dir is stabilized.

Comment: I have been using the Pages Dir for about a year or so, but I started a new project with the App Router when they said it was ready for use in production. This is a bit of a dealbreaker.